Apache Jena Fuseki Reasoning, online update and named graphs possible?
i can't find good answers or resources on if the following setup is possible in Apache Jena Fuseki:

The database should be updatable. I want to add rdf data while the server is running.

By uploading new rdf data, fuseki should automatically run inference on that new rdf data.

I somehow want to group rdf statements so that I can dynamically delete that set of triples after uploading it to the graph. I thought about named graphs but I'm not sure if inference works on named graphs. Or rather, the reasoning should actually be performed on the union graph.

With every sparql query I only want to query a default unified graph where also reasoning had been done.


I read some other questions and conversations but couldn't figure out if this scenario is possible. The apache jena documentation did not really help me either.

What sort of inference capabilities are you wanting?

Hey i would need the mini owl reasoner http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2003/OWLMiniFBRuleReasoner.

Deleting a group of statements while still having the inference on the union graph is the hard part here. If it is RDFS inference then there is a fully dynamic RDFS dataset. It might also be possible if all the rules are backwards chaining. But manipulating the underlying graph while the server is running and still having a inference-union is the problem. You could try asking on the users mailing list.

Alright, thanks, I will do that :)
